# DNS Domain Registry WhoIs Match Not Found

Tags: whois

I am monitoring a domain for when it expires. I am familiar with the expiring domain process: grace period, redemption period and then deleted.

What has me baffled is when I search for this particular domain in any WhoIs database (NetworkSolution, ICANN, etc). The result is:

```
No match for "<domain name>" in the registrar database.
```

**From NetworkSolutions:**

> The previous information has been obtained either directly from the registrant or a registrar of the domain name other than Network Solutions. Network Solutions, therefore, does not guarantee its accuracy or completeness.
>
> Show underlying registry data for this record

The last line is a link to some brief information that was in the registry. Most notable information is the WhoIs server name and the registrar (GoDaddy).

Here is the output from that link

```
Domain Name: <domain name>
Registrar: GODADDY.COM, LLC
Sponsoring Registrar IANA ID: 146
Whois Server: whois.godaddy.com
Referral URL: http://www.godaddy.com
Name Server: No nameserver
Status: redemptionPeriod https://www.icann.org/epp#redemptionPeriod
Updated Date: <date>
Creation Date: <date>
Expiration Date: <date>
```

**From ICANN WhoIs Search**

> The requested second-level domain was not found in the Registry or Registrar’s WHOIS Server.

Now, ICANN does not provide any information on the registry.

So, if there is no match, technically wouldn't it be available for purchase? How is this possible? Shouldn't there always be information in the registrar even in redemptionPeriod.

Comment: While I see the conflict there is in posting an example, it would be really helpful to have an example domain.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not explicit enough, and of course without a domain name it is difficult to help you.

Some points though:

- ICANN is not a registrar, and as such does not have a whois service that could help you, you should contact the registries whois server directly
- for the same reason, first contact registries whois servers before registrars one; registries are authoritative on their data

As for the discrepancies you may see, I would refer you to my other extensive reply that deals with the subject: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/407030/211833

You should then understand that a registry may have deleted a domain name and hence making it not showing anymore through its whois server while the sponsoring registrar may not have updated its database and hence its own whois server would display something else. There are also no obligations for them to be updated in real time while on the field they may be.